# PyQGIS output to specific layer

Tags: layers, pyqgis-3, time

I have a Python script that I have exported from a QGIS model and I want to specify the layer it creates as output.

If `defaultValue=None` it outputs `'Reportpmbc'`: `'Centroids_9c779c9c_4bcc_471b_971e_fbea3bb27c7d'`, in the log window and a `'Centroids'` layer is created in the project.

I want it to create a temporary layer `'Report-PMBC'` as below but it won't run.  (“.” files are not supported as outputs for this algorithm)

What am I missing in the statement below? I think I have to create a temporary layer in memory and write to it but I am not sure how to do that.

```py
 self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Reportpmbc', 'Report-PMBC', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint, createByDefault=True, defaultValue='Report-PMBC'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the variable Report-PMBC in your algorithm like this:

```
class YourAlg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    Report_PMBC = 'Report-PMBC'
```

Add the parameter like this in you initAlgorithm method:

```
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.Report-PMBC,
            'Report-PMBC',
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint))
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't appear to quite have it.  Please see below;            
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 397, in processAlgorithm
KeyError: 'Reportpmbc'

Execution failed after 10.94 seconds

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Tell me if you did like that.

Comment: self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(self.Report-PMBC,'Report-PMBC',QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint))

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 224, in runAlgorithm
    exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)
  File "<string>", line 10
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: I added the two rows as you suggested and it returned the error in the third comment above.  The second row you suggested is just under the line 10 it seems to be blowing up on.

Comment: # Drop field(s)
        alg_params = {
            'COLUMN': 'layer;path',
            'INPUT': outputs['AddAutoincrementalRightsofwayAndLeases']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['RightsofwayAndLeases']
        }
        outputs['DropFields'] = processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['ReportrightsofwayAndLeases'] = outputs['DropFields']['OUTPUT']
        return results

In this case I get a layer added "Remaining fields"  I want "RightsofwayAndLeases" to be the temporary layer output.

Comment: I have this script processing now but get a runtime error in QGIS: 2020-01-15T10:30:35     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "", line 225, in processAlgorithm
             KeyError: 'Report_PMBC'  Line 225 is this:        'OUTPUT': parameters['Report_PMBC']